# How can I don't use global variables in this page?

Tags: php

on php document, I made this function.

```
function getPrices($url) {
    global $priceList;  // declare global . point of this.

    $src = file_get_contents_curl($url);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $selector = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $results = $selector->query('//table/tr/td/span');

    foreach($results as $node) {
        array_push($priceList, $node->nodeValue);
    }
}
```

and bottom of page, I called it several.

```
$priceList = array();

getPrices("http://finance.naver.com/item/sise_day.nhn?code=005930");
getPrices("http://finance.naver.com/item/sise_day.nhn?code=005930&page=2");
getPrices("http://finance.naver.com/item/sise_day.nhn?code=005930&page=3");
```

and display it.

```
echo $priceList[1];
echo $priceList[2];
echo $priceList[3];
```

The problem is I'm using CMS kinds of Joomla, Wordpress, and they do not support using **global variable** So I don't know how to I make this without using global. How can I make it? I need many pages to scrapping, so I'm very afraid. if I scrap just one page,

return in function, 
and

```
$priceList = getPrices("http://finance.naver.com/item/sise_day.nhn?code=$code");
```

But I don't know many scrapping case. Please help me...

Comment: may be you can store it in the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return the partial results from the function and [merge](http://docs.php.net/array_merge) them into the complete results array.

```
<?php
$result = [];

$result = array_merge($result, getSomeValues());
$result = array_merge($result, getSomeValues());
$result = array_merge($result, getSomeValues());

var_export($result);

function getSomeValues() {
    static $i = 0;
    // returning a partial result of three elements
    return [ $i++, $i++, $i++ ];
}
```

prints

```
array (
  0 => 0,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 2,
  3 => 3,
  4 => 4,
  5 => 5,
  6 => 6,
  7 => 7,
  8 => 8,
)
```

Comment: why `$i` is declared as static?

Comment: I wanted getSomeValue() to return [0,1,2],[3,4,5] and [6,7,8]. `static $i` was just the shortest way I know of to accomplish this ;-)

Comment: I would go with `rand()` :D

Comment: rand() was my first pick, too. But I wanted it reproducible ;-)

Comment: rand() using a fixed salt value?

Comment: maybe, I just chose `static`. Why not?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't be using global variables anyways. It's bad practice.  Here is one way you can restructure it:

```
function getPrices($url) {
    // this is just a local scoped temp var
    $priceList = array();

    $src = file_get_contents_curl($url);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $selector = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $results = $selector->query('//table/tr/td/span');

    foreach($results as $node) {
        array_push($priceList, $node->nodeValue);
    }
    // return the price list
    return $priceList;
}

// here is your real price list
$priceList = array();
// array of urls
$urls = array(
  "http://finance.naver.com/item/sise_day.nhn?code=005930",
  "http://finance.naver.com/item/sise_day.nhn?code=005930&page=2",
  "http://finance.naver.com/item/sise_day.nhn?code=005930&page=3"
  // etc..
);

// loop through the urls and assign the results to the price list
foreach ($urls as $url) {
  $priceList[] = getPrices($url);
}
```

Now you have `$priceList` as an array to do whatever with. Or, if you are looking to immediately output.. you can just skip putting it into `$priceList` and do your output in the loop above

Answer (score 0):

You could store the partial results as elements of an array of results.
This way you'd keep some of the information of "what" produced the result.
(You could even use the url as array index)

```
<?php
$result = [];
$result[] = getSomeValues();
$result[] = getSomeValues();
$result[] = getSomeValues();

// now $result is an array of arrays of (some scalar value)
// so your iteration has to be changed
foreach( $results as $presult ) {
  foreach( $presult as $element ) {
    ..do something with $element
  }
}

// or you can "hide" the nesting with 
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($result));
foreach($it as $e ) {
    echo $e, ', ';
} // see http://docs.php.net/spl

function getSomeValues() {
    static $i = 0;
    return [ $i++, $i++, $i++ ];
}
```

The RecursiveIteratorIterator/foreach part prints `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,`